# An unknown table

Tags: knowledge, pattern, video-games

Yesterday my nerdy roommate was playing his favorite videogame. After they finished, they left me this message:

> IwaendnIttocatuhgehtrusoimePnsoofkéamlonph

As well as this table which I tried to decipher without success:

```
201   3   2  14  11  13
201   9   1   0   0  15
201   6  12   3   5  10
201   5   4   5   4   7
201   4   8   9  10  10
201  10  13  14   3   8

???  12   6   7  13   9
```

The first three-digit number in the last row is missing, what could it be? I suspect it is not just a $201$: my roommate is such a nerd...

Comment: I can see what he went out for, but I don't know if the numbers actually relate to deducing how I should see that.

Comment: I'll add a moderate hint tomorrow unless someone solves this puzzle first

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could the answer be

> 131?

As @Stiv pointed out, the message translates to:

> I went to the ruins of alph and I caught some Pokemon

What does 201 mean:

> In the Ruins of Alph you can catch the pokemon Unown, which is number 201 in the pokedex.
>  Unowns come in different forms representing letters. Quoting Bulbapedia: "In the Generation II games, Unown's form is determined by its IVs".

What do the numbers mean:

> The decimal values in the question can be converted to binary values. Each row of five 4-bit values represent the IV's.

So the result will be:

> 201   3   2  14  11  13  ->  201: 0011 0010 1110 1011 1101
>
>  201   9   1   0   0  15  ->  201: 1001 0001 0000 0000 1111
>
>  201   6  12   3   5  10  ->  201: 0110 1100 0011 0101 1010
>
>  201   5   4   5   4   7  ->  201: 0101 0100 0101 0100 0111
>
>  201   4   8   9  10  10  ->  201: 0100 1000 1001 1010 1010
>
>  201  10  13  14   3   8  ->  201: 1010 1101 1110 0011 1000
>
>
>  From [Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Individual_values#Unown.27s_letter):
>
>  Unown's form is calculated by taking the middle two bits of the last four 4-bit values. Then add them together, convert it to decimal, dived by 10 and round the number down, then add 1, and you end up with a number corresponding to a letter:
>
>
>  0011 0010 1110 1011 1101 ->  01 01 11 01 10 -> 01 01110110 -> 11 -> 12
>
>  1001 0001 0000 0000 1111 ->  00 00 00 00 11 -> 00 00000011 -> 0  -> 1
>
>  0110 1100 0011 0101 1010 ->  11 10 01 10 01 -> 11 10011001 -> 15 -> 16
>
>  0101 0100 0101 0100 0111 ->  10 10 10 10 11 -> 10 10101011 -> 17 -> 18
>
>  0100 1000 1001 1010 1010 ->  10 00 00 01 01 -> 10 00000101 -> 0  -> 1
>
>  1010 1101 1110 0011 1000 ->  01 10 11 01 00 -> 01 10110100 -> 18 -> 19
>
>  12 1 16 18 1 19 translates to Lapras
>
>
>  Lapras' pokedex number is 131, so I think the answer is 131, and the numbers behind 131 are the IV-values of Lapras.

Comment: Oh, well done sir! I spotted what the 5 values likely represented (A, D, SA, SD, S) and then got stuck, having totally forgotten that you could use those for any real purpose re the 'mon in question (d'oh!). Well done for wrapping this one up so thoroughly... +1

Comment: Well done David, you were so fast. Congrats on your first accepted answer!

Comment: Also: where did he get that rot13(yncenf) from? XD

Answer (score 2):

Partial guess:

> The message has 42 letters and there are 42 numbers in the grid (including '???').
>  The puzzle is about a video game and the tangle of letters includes the word
>  **Pokémon**

Comment: It appears to say, rot13(V jrag gb trg fbzr Cbxrzba). Dunno if a decryption is needed though.

Comment: @MacGyver88 rot13(Gung vf rknpgyl unys bs gur yrggref).

Comment: Right, math isn't my strong suit. I just see it there. I can't prove it if a proof is needed. It takes me too long.

Comment: rot13(Zl xvqf hfrq gb cynl guvf tnzr. Cbxrzba Tb. Gur ahzoref cebonoyl unir fbzrguvat gb qb jvgu gur Cbxrzba lbh'ir pnhtug be fbzrguvat. Znlor gurl yriryrq hc naq unir gb pngpu zber?) That's all I have.

Comment: Perhaps, but the message has only one **c**.

Comment: rot13(Nyfb abg fher vs guvf vf gur evtug nccebnpu ohg vs lbh fcyvg gur gjb unyirf lbh trg "V jnag gb trg fbzr Cbxézba" naq "raq V pnghu u ehvaf bs  nycu" Abj boivbhfyl gur frpbaq ovg vfa'g n shyy fragrapr ohg vg frrzf yvxr vs jr punatr hc gur jbeqf n ovg jr zvtug trg fbzrguvat gurer...)

Comment: I didn't use a c for my part? Nice catch,@gabbo1092.

Comment: @gabbo1092 (and others) It's actually rot13(V jrag gb gur ehvaf bs nycu naq V pnhtug fbzr Cbxrzba) - think Gold and Silver, #201, and the title pun... ;-)

Comment: @Stiv, I don't play enough games anymore. Nice.

Comment: @Stiv nice guess, that is correct! Go on now and find the complete answer